# How can I remove lines that don't contain a number after "-" In Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

How can I remove lines that don't contain a number after "-" In Notepad++

Example

```
Value1-iiieoeiampl
Value2-ah8e83e9e
Value3-e9ASjdds9ja3
Value4-eoDJEjieee
```

What I need

```
Value2-ah8e83e9e
Value3-e9ASjdds9ja3
```

Tried using "^\D*$." but just delete the line because number in "Value"

Answer (score 1):

Try `^.*-[^0-9]*$`

This will select all chars up to the - and then not select any rows with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you this worked.

Before you posted was messing around and had this written out using online regex tester. It worked but required 2 commands.

Delete the "-" and everything after "-" without numbers = -\D*$
Then
Delete lines without "-" = ^[^-]*$

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+-\D+(?:\R|\Z)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .+      # 1 or more any character but newline
    -       # an hyphen
    \D+     # 1 or more any character that is not a digit
    (?:     # start non capture group
      \R    # any kind of linebreak
     |      # OR
      \Z    # end of file
    )       # end group
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Value2-ah8e83e9e
Value3-e9ASjdds9ja3
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]